# Powershell Passing Variables with Procedure Call

Tags: sql, powershell, stored-procedures

Updated as I think I'm getting closer. New error below.

I am getting incorrect/invalid snytax errors when trying to run this. Can anyone guide me on what to change?

```
#Test-DbaConnection -SqlInstance $SqlInstance
$Database = "ITSBilling"
$results = Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance $SqlInstance -Database $Database -Query "sp_APP_Create_Universal_Charge_Numbers 14, @PARENT = '$newserver', @LEVEL1 = '$billingsharename', @LEVEL2 = '$location', @LEVEL3 = '$billingsharename', @LEVEL4 = '$approver1', @CHARGECODES = '$chargecode', @STATUS = '@STATUS OUTPUT', @STATUSDESCRIPTION = '@STATUSDESCRIPTION OUTPUT'"
$results
```

```
Invoke-Sqlcmd : Error converting data type varchar to int. 
 Msg 8114, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_APP_Create_Universal_Charge_Numbers, Line 0.
```

Comment: Do you not need to do named parameters for every parameter? what is the 14 for? Also i think you need to declare your output parameters. Try printing out `$billingquery` and running that in SSMS, it will then tell you what is wrong

Comment: Can you add a copy of the exact error message into your question.

Comment: As a folllow up, can you add the value of ```$billingquery```  (use e.g. ```write-host "query = '$billingquery'"``` to get this) - it's possible you've got a special character like an apostrophe in your data that is breaking the query syntax (```$approver1 = "Ryan O'Neal"```). If you need to anonymise the data, only replace alpha-numeric characters, and leave everything like spaces, quotes, etc so we can see them. And try running that exact same query in SSMS to see if it works there...

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax looks technically correct, but anytime you are creating a long string with multiple variables and you are mixing single quotes and double quotes things can get confusing quickly.

Try the format operator syntax instead.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7.2

Change this:

```
$billingquery = "EXEC SP_APP_CREATE_UNIVERSAL_CHARGE_NUMBERS 14, @SERVERNAME='$newserver',@SHARENAME='$billingsharename',@VOLUME='$location',@CONTACT='$approver1',CHARGECODES='$chargecode',@STATUS=@STATUS OUTPUT, @STATUSDESCRIPTION = @STATUSDESCRIPTION OUTPUT"
```

To this:

```
$billingquery = ("EXEC SP_APP_CREATE_UNIVERSAL_CHARGE_NUMBERS 14, @SERVERNAME='{0}',@SHARENAME='{1}',@VOLUME='{2}',@CONTACT='{3}',CHARGECODES='{4}',@STATUS=@STATUS OUTPUT, @STATUSDESCRIPTION = @STATUSDESCRIPTION OUTPUT" -f $newserver, $billingsharename, $location, $approver1, $chargecode)
```

Also, write the variable to the screen or a log file so you can verify it is formatted corrected:

```
Write-Output $billingquery
```

Comment: Could you check my update and new error please?